Unable to load into installed linuxmint os
I currently have Windows and Arch Linux installed on a drive with a GPT partition and grub. I am now trying to install Linux Mint alongside these two.
I am installing Mint on a second HDD (same PC) with an MBR partition and I am having trouble running the installed OS. I have tried adding it—not together, but in different tries—to both EFI (one in the GPT partition and one in the MBR partition) and both are giving errors.
The errors are "load kernel first, msdos not found". I will try to attach a screenshot. It comes at startup when I try to boot Linux Mint from grub.
I have tried everything. I can't format the entire second disk to GPT since I have data in other partitions of the disk. Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried changing boot to legacy, it also didn't work.
There seems to be a tool, mbr2gpt but I can't get it to work. I have no OS other than Linux Mint (installing) in the second HDD.
I don't know if its gpt issue or something else.
Ubuntu also seems to have issue. It said some error like not authorized to access grub in gpt.
I have tried to install grub in mbr but it seems to overwrite grub with gpt and I couldn't login to arch.
Edit1:-
This is the error on selecting linuxmint from grub

Edit2:-Adding boot-info from boot repair
boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20240525_2040]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
    for (,msdos3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
   
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  LMDE 6 (faye)
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/GRUB/grubx64.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:      
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Arch Linux
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 44096 of /dev/sdc1 for its
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed.
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdc2 starts
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk,
                       sdc2 starts at sector 61437880. According to the info
                       in the boot sector, sdc2 has 0 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootaa64.efi /efi/Boot/bootarm.efi
                       /efi/Boot/bootia32.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
                       /efi/Rufus/exfat_aa64.efi /efi/Rufus/exfat_arm.efi
                       /efi/Rufus/exfat_ia32.efi /efi/Rufus/exfat_x64.efi
                       /efi/Rufus/ntfs_aa64.efi /efi/Rufus/ntfs_arm.efi
                       /efi/Rufus/ntfs_ia32.efi /efi/Rufus/ntfs_x64.efi


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   LMDE 6 (faye) on sda5
OS#2:   Arch Linux on sdb5
OS#3:   Windows 8 or 10 on sdb3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (LMDE 6 (faye), faye, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 79CN46WW(V3.05)(1.70) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* EFI USB Device (Generic Flash Disk) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(0,0)/HD(2,MBR,0x29c46,0x3a977b8,0x800)RC
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager HD(1,GPT,d51273d0-888f-4ca8-9490-a9ba15966eae,0x7d800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a............. ...
Boot0003* GRUB HD(1,GPT,d51273d0-888f-4ca8-9490-a9ba15966eae,0x7d800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network RC

04fb9982cb9d93492d3220cf08f03f02   sdb1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a2418029711ac3b3e3bfd27223a1fb6d   sdb1/GRUB/grubx64.efi
04fb9982cb9d93492d3220cf08f03f02   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
8ea8644096bf0b8227e6541e9a790f8c   sdb1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
e099b8f8463ef839720fda267e70eeb1   sdc2/Boot/bootaa64.efi
cfd0ce50df258fc747f5753ecf6ec312   sdc2/Boot/bootarm.efi
19a65a943434a625a53490391fa28349   sdc2/Boot/bootia32.efi
3fdfc83db7958b2eac1e720334f12147   sdc2/Boot/bootx64.efi
4a4e8e66e0d3712f19d964a7bca4fafc   sdc2/Rufus/exfat_aa64.efi
93f66a43d49990f986a81c67843d66a5   sdc2/Rufus/exfat_arm.efi
3c5f23f198267df4a64fe2a3587039e7   sdc2/Rufus/exfat_ia32.efi
81d015f35982a0bbf4056f09a2eca39a   sdc2/Rufus/exfat_x64.efi
a03e27b0e7f2e03519166bf6b41f68c5   sdc2/Rufus/ntfs_aa64.efi
2f31c70d3f4235476cd9ed6a18e13221   sdc2/Rufus/ntfs_arm.efi
7e7e67c33ce9ff2961a4be4080d23352   sdc2/Rufus/ntfs_ia32.efi
30c7e0752040cf5e31843d897a53e055   sdc2/Rufus/ntfs_x64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : is-GPT, no-BIOSboot, has---ESP, not-usb, not-mmc, has-os, has-win, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : notGPT, no-BIOSboot, has---ESP, usb-disk, not-mmc, no-os, no-wind, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT, no-BIOSboot, has-noESP, not-usb, not-mmc, has-os, no-wind, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, farbios
sdb5 : is-os, 64, pacman, no-docgrub, grub2, grub-install, grubenv-ok, grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub, farbios
sdb3 : is-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, farbios
sdb1 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
sdc2 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
sda4 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, farbios
sda2 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
sda5 : is-os, 64, apt-get, grub-pc , grub2, grub-install, no-grubenv, update-grub, not-far
sda1 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far
sda6 : no-os, 32, nopakmgr, no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall, no-grubenv, noupdategrub, not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sdb5 : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sdb3 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sdb1 : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sdc2 : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sda4 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sda2 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sda5 : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sda1 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot
sda6 : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab, no-nt, no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid, no-bmgr, notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sdb
sdb5 : not--sepboot, with-boot, fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr, with--usr, fstab-without-usr, std-grub.d, sdb
sdb3 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sdb
sdb1 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sdb
sdc2 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sdc
sda4 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda
sda2 : not--sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda
sda5 : not--sepboot, with-boot, fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr, with--usr, fstab-without-usr, std-grub.d, sda
sda1 : is---sepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda
sda6 : maybesepboot, no---boot, part-has-no-fstab, not-sep-usr, no---usr, part-has-no-fstab, no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xf638964d
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2          206848  39266303  39059456  18.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3        39270398 205006847 165736450    79G  5 Extended
sda4       205006848 488392703 283385856 135.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda5        39272448  72040447  32768000  15.6G 83 Linux
sda6        72042496 135530495  63488000  30.3G 83 Linux
sda7       135532544 146796543  11264000   5.4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: 3DAEA9F5-FE33-4404-8FF7-EFDA8914769F
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdb1     514048    718847    204800   100M EFI System
sdb2     718848    751615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sdb3     751616 512751615 512000000 244.1G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  512751616 753379327 240627712 114.7G Microsoft basic data
sdb5  753379328 921151487 167772160    80G Linux filesystem
sdb6  921151488 937701375  16549888   7.9G Linux swap
Disk sdc: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00029c46
      Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *        2048 61437879 61435832 29.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sdc2       61437880 61439927     2048    1M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA TOSHIBA MK2555GS:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32::;
2:106MB:20.1GB:20.0GB:ntfs::;
3:20.1GB:105GB:84.9GB:::;
5:20.1GB:36.9GB:16.8GB:ext4::;
6:36.9GB:69.4GB:32.5GB:ext4::;
7:69.4GB:75.2GB:5767MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:105GB:250GB:145GB:ntfs::;
sdb:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA GIGABYTE GP-GSTF:;
1:263MB:368MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:368MB:385MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:385MB:263GB:262GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:263GB:386GB:123GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:386GB:472GB:85.9GB:ext4::;
6:472GB:480GB:8474MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
sdc:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:ntfs::boot;
2:31.5GB:31.5GB:1049kB:::esp;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 71678MiB:100101MiB:28423MiB
sdb: 0.02MiB:251MiB:251MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
├─sda1 vfat     5723-D062                            f638964d-01                                                
├─sda2 ntfs     267C88077C87CFCB                     f638964d-02                          New Volume            
├─sda3                                               f638964d-03                                                
├─sda4 ntfs     DC8C86758C8649CA                     f638964d-04                          New Volume            
├─sda5 ext4     36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd f638964d-05                                                
├─sda6 ext4     e9f531a4-b065-4a8c-a0d3-756b486e5d84 f638964d-06                                                
└─sda7 swap     35401696-3044-46b3-82f3-d6eb6e9151a9 f638964d-07                                                
sdb                                                                                                              
├─sdb1 vfat     3416-50EE                            d51273d0-888f-4ca8-9490-a9ba15966eae                        EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                               751b43fb-bbae-402c-87ef-8a8745bb3804                        Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3 ntfs     FCB040C8B0408ADA                     fb0cea09-889d-43f1-89a1-e6ea4e84b376                        Basic data partition
├─sdb4 ntfs     3894A28694A2466A                     97dcb553-4f8a-4b44-9e73-8176de7968ce New Volume             Basic data partition
├─sdb5 ext4     959afc21-ab26-4c23-82b1-cd4ad6afb826 82c37fd0-5918-437f-af1e-ad9d408c52f9                        
└─sdb6 swap     302c29c8-cfc0-43af-a5ac-49ecb572b079 57783657-fb60-47ae-befe-2f8b2780c769                        
sdc                                                                                                              
├─sdc1 ntfs     64D05309D052E0BA                     00029c46-01                          LMDE 6 Cinnamon 64-bit
└─sdc2 vfat     5FA3-F2DA                            00029c46-02                          UEFI_NTFS              

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

              Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1         0 100% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2        1G  94% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda4        7G  95% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5      7.4G  46% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6     28.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sdb1     68.5M  29% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb3    175.7G  28% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdb4     44.5G  61% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdb5       40G  44% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb5
/dev/sdc1     26.7G   9% /run/live/medium
/dev/sdc1     26.7G   9% /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
/dev/sdc2      126K  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc2
overlay        1.8G   5% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1    vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda2    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5    ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda6    ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1    vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb3    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb4    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb5    ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdc1    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc1    fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc2    vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64                         1
            ?? = ??             initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64                      2
            ?? = ??             initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64.dpkg-bak             2

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
UUID=3416-50EE /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
UUID=36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=35401696-3044-46b3-82f3-d6eb6e9151a9 swap swap sw 0 0
UUID=e9f531a4-b065-4a8c-a0d3-756b486e5d84 /home ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  28.007579803 = 30.072909824   boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-12-amd64                    1
  28.007579803 = 30.072909824   vmlinuz                                        1
  28.007579803 = 30.072909824   vmlinuz.old                                    1
  29.340026855 = 31.503613952   boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-12-amd64                 1
  29.340026855 = 31.503613952   initrd.img                                     1
  29.340026855 = 31.503613952   initrd.img.old                                 1

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14123 Apr 23  2023 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 23  2023 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12923 Apr 23  2023 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 23  2023 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Feb 26  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 23  2023 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 23  2023 41_custom

=========================== sda5/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ===========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?} --version > /dev/null
      prepare_grub_to_access_device "$(${grub_probe} --target=device ${ESP})" | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
cat << EOF
chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi

====================== sdb5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Arch Linux   959afc21-ab26-4c23-82b1-cd4ad6afb826
Arch Linux, with Linux linux   959afc21-ab26-4c23-82b1-cd4ad6afb826
Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)   gnulinux-linux-fallback-959afc21-ab26-4c23-82b1-cd4ad6afb826
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-3416-50EE
LMDE 6 (faye) (on sdb5)   36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
UUID=959afc21-ab26-4c23-82b1-cd4ad6afb826 /         ext4       rw,relatime 0 1
UUID=3416-50EE       /efi       vfat       rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 2
UUID=302c29c8-cfc0-43af-a5ac-49ecb572b079 none       swap       defaults   0 0

======================= sdb5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sdb5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 433.167007446 = 465.109532672  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 384.229732513 = 412.563533824  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 379.989253998 = 408.010354688  boot/vmlinuz-linux                             2
 395.520416260 = 424.686813184  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 427.176753998 = 458.677547008  boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img             12
 365.950191498 = 392.936026112  boot/initramfs-linux.img                       2

===================== sdb5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12579 Mar 16 19:09 10_linux
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 May 18 14:48 15_ostree -> /usr/lib/libostree/grub2-15_ostree
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14341 Mar 16 19:09 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Mar 16 19:09 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12289 Mar 16 19:09 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Mar 16 19:09 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Mar 16 19:09 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Mar 16 19:09 41_custom

============================ sdb5/etc/grub.d/25_bli ============================

#! /bin/sh
set -e
# grub-mkconfig helper script.
# Copyright (C) 2023  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
cat << EOF
if [ "\$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
  insmod bli
fi
EOF

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start LMDE 6 64-bit
Start LMDE 6 64-bit (compatibility mode)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Memory test

========================= sdc1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg

================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi of
sda5,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the LMDE 6 (faye) entry (sdb1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

Edit:- This is menu entry in grub config
menuentry 'LMDE 6 (faye) (on /dev/sdb5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz.old--36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos5  36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz.old root=/dev/sdb5
        initrd /initrd.img.old
    }

This is the UUID in sdb5 where os is installed
/dev/sdb5: UUID="36e0d91a-caa4-40b8-bd15-d264910228dd" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f638964d-05"

The UUID seems to be different in the error during boot. But grub config seems to be correct

What computer is it (brand name and model)? Which version of Linux Mint are you trying to install? Which tool/method did you use to make the USB boot drive? Can you remove or otherwise disable the other HDD, while trying to install Linux Mint?

@sudodus I used rufus to format the usb with os, I just downloaded latest linux mint from website. I think its 21.3. I can remove the other hdd temporarily, but I a doubt if there will be grub conflict with the gpt and mbr partition when i reintroduce the other hdd.

What computer is it (brand name and model)? Linux can install into and boot from both GPT and MBR (MSDOS partition table) and should tolerate that one drive has GPT and the other drive has MBR.  Rufus is a good tool. Did you check with sha256sum that the downloaded iso file is good? When in UEFI mode, is 'secure boot' activated? In that case, please try turning it off. - Finally, I think it is worth trying to install Linux Mint, when the other HDD is removed or otherwise disabled.

Since you have Windows and GPT, the computer boots in UEFI mode. This makes it convenient to install also Linux Mint in UEFI mode (otherwise you must change boot mode every time that you want to switch between Windows (and probably also Arch) and the new Linux Mint).

Its a lenovo G-520. I think rufus is fine because i setup arch using the same. I want to use UEFI but i switched to legacy only when the other didn't work. Yes the secure boot is off. I double checked because when you switch between legacy to UEFI, secure boot is automatically turned on. So i turned it off each time.

Also should I format the usb with MBR or GPT?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Partition table type is not a real problem. You can have ESP and EFI grub on an "MBR drive", although the "user-friendly" distro installer may not present the option to you. Besides, if you install multiple instances of grub, often it means that you want to use your UEFI/BIOS boot menu to choose which to boot. (Although if they are of the same variant (EFI or BIOS/legacy), it would be possible to chainload one from another.) I am not sure how you got into this mess, or like, which grub you are talking about...

Also, are you having a shared /boot partition for the two Linux installations?

At present, grub is fine. I ran grub-config in arch iso and it fixed the grub. But linuxmint is still broken. My doubt is if it is possible to install 2 seperate grub. or will it conflict?

At first I tried a couple of times with seperate boot partitions, currently i am trying to write to single efi present in gpt with windows and arch

@JustaNobody they would conflict only if: 1. you have a shared /boot partition (and don't know how to workaround it with --boot-directory of grub-install), 2. both are of the BIOS/legacy variant (i.e., i386-pc target) and their MBR boot code are being installed to the MBR of the same drive, 3. both are of the EFI variant and trying to take the same path under the ESP (this pretty much never happens unless you make it so). (The problem is, the first two might "happen" when a distro installer is dumb / bugged, like installing to a drive's MBR even when you specify the other drive.)

@JustaNobody You can opt to have one single ESP for all three OS installations, but then DO NOT use the ESP for /boot (i.e., you'd need to make sure it is mounted on /boot/efi instead in both Linux installations).

Hey I was doing some troubleshooting and found that the UUID in the error seems to different from the UUID of sdb5. But grub config seems to have the correct ID. Is it some error?

@TomYan Hey while installing linux mint I did notice that the efi partition was mounted in /boot/efi. But in arch, I mounted it in /boot directly. Is that the issue? I do not know what ESP is? Is it same as efi?
